# How many convex functions are there in $[0,1]^2$?

Tags: algorithms, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Consider the square $[0,1]^2$. Assume that this region is divided into $N=K^2$ equispaced grid points. How many convex curves can be drawn in terms of $K$?

The points $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ are known to be on the convex curve. I am interested in the answer of this questions due to two reasons:

$1.$ I would like to consider $K\rightarrow \infty$ and compare the total number of convex functions to the total number of other types of functions for example (decreasing, etc.)

$2.$ Later I would like to write a program to realize all such discrete convex functions in order to perform optimization over all these functions (for a specific $K$).

I would be also happy to hear any ideas about how to realize this algorithmically.

Here is an example, where one can see examples of three different convex functions:

[image]

In this example there are altogether $N=121$ grid points and the distance between each neighboring pair of grid points both in $x$ and $y$ direction is $0.1$.

So, for every value on the $x$ axis, there will be a corresponding value on the $y$ axis.

**ADDED (15.07.2018):** I programmed and obtained the grid. Using this approach it is impossible to get all convex functions as $N\rightarrow \infty$. I bet we are not even near. Consider the convex function which linearly decreases from $(0,1)$ to $(0.4,0.2)$ and again linearly decreases from $(0.4,0.2)$ to $(1,0)$. It is impossible to get this function with this approach. No mater how fine the grid is, there are infinitely many other functions which are not achieved.

Comment: Can you provide some positive and negative examples of such functions? Or even better a drawing?

Comment: yes I can. Just a second please. I also forgot that $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ should be on the convex function.

Comment: The function in your diagram does not appear to be convex; the curve bends _down_ at $(0.3, 0.5)$.

Comment: (Oh, and you have $121$ grid points rather than $100$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm you are right. so just a fast illustration without any care about anything. Let $(0.2,0.5)$ and $(0.3,0.4)$ be the related points. As you can see, my drawing is also horrible:)

Comment: @HenningMakholm btw can you see the example now? in my computer I cannot see the figure right now, as well as my own profile picture.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: You may have some weird local block of images from stack.imgur.com (I think I read rumors recently about some cybernanny software or other considering it bad, but seeing how it's Stack Exchange's official image host ...)

Comment: Would the function with breakpoints at $(0, 1), (.2, 0.7),$ and $(1, 0)$ *only* be allowed as a result? Or is the fact that when $x = 0.3$, the corresponding $y$ value is not a multiple of $0.1$ a problem?

Comment: @JohnHughes I just read your comment. Sorry for answering you late. The function is discrete on the given grid. Consider that we have $N\times N$ grid where $N$ goes to $\infty$. At the limit we will be at the continuous world. For this example, the only points that we consider can be the grid points. Other points are not elements of the domain and co domain. So they do not exist. If we increase $N$ all points of interest will be valid points. The question is given such a grid with $N\times N$ points how many convex curves can possibly be drawn? $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ are the only two must points

Comment: For the algorithmic approach: since the slope must be increasing, you can find values of the function at each abscissa, starting from the left: the number of possibilities for the ordinate is easy to find, and is dictated by the previous slope and the previous value of $y$ (and the fact that you must end at $(1,0)$). It's also obvious that these convex functions are a subset of the decreasing functions.

Comment: What do you mean by convex curves? It seems you mean not ever going up.

Comment: Oh... definition: A convex function is a continuous function whose value at the midpoint of every interval in its domain does not exceed the arithmetic mean of its values at the ends of the interval. - Wolfram Mathworld Essentially meaning it doesn't go up...

Comment: In the recent edit -- if I understand it correctly -- what you're observing is that not every convex function $[0,1]\to[0,1]$ can be approximated by your grid functions. If your goal was to compare, in some way, the "volume" of the set of convex functions on the continuous $[0,1]\to[0,1]$ to the volume of other kinds of function, then I think the basic idea of approximating the function spaces by two-dimensional grids fails, and if I were you I would be asking a _new_, less specific function of something like "what would be a good way to compare these sets of functions?"

Comment: One way forward might be to consider for each $N$ _all_ functions that are pointwise linear with possible bends at one of $N$ equispaced points -- but where the $y$ coordinate at those points is _not_ restricted to be a grid point. For each $N$ the space of all such functions $[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]^N$ which has a nice Lebesgue measure, and you can then compare the measure of the set of convex functions to the measure of the set of e.g. decreasing functions. Then you could hope that this ratio would converge (or have other quantifiable behavior) for $N\to\infty$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you very much for the comment. Yes this is a very good idea and probably I may need to ask a new question for that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure that this is what you want, but here is my thinking about it:

If $n$ is the number of divisions of unity ($n=10$ in your drawing), and $x_i, i=1,2,\ldots n$ is the number of divisions traveled downwards by each segment of your curve (for the green curve $x_1,\ldots ,x_{10}$ would be $5,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0$), then your problem could be formulated as the number of solutions of the following integer equation:

$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=n$

subject to:

$x_1\ge x_2\ge\ldots\ge x_n\ge 0$

We can observe that each solution of this integer equation can be put in $1:1$ correspondence with a partition of $n$ (by ignoring the zeros). For the green line, this is:

$10=5+2+1+1+1$

So the number of convex functions equals $p(n)$, which is the number of partitions of $n$.

Unfortunately, $p(n)$ does not have a nice closed-form formula, but you can see the Wikipedia page [Partition_(number_theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) for more details, recurrences, asymptotics, etc.

EDIT: To address OP's question about comparing $p(n)$ with the number of non-increasing functions:

If $q(n)$ is the number of non-increasing functions (not necessarily convex), then by reusing the previous notation, we get that $q(n)$ is the number of integer solutions of the following equation:

$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=n$

subject to:

$x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n\ge 0$

This is a classic [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem (theorem two), whose solution is:

$q(n)= {n + n - 1 \choose n - 1}={2n-1\choose n-1}$

A [quick check](https://is.gd/QfHV9m) on Wolfram Alpha shows that $\frac{q(n)}{p(n)}\to\infty$, so $p(n)=o(q(n))$

Comment: It would be nice to come up with a recursive formula to count them in exponential time. And I think it should be able to reduce it to a polynomial in time solution using dynamic programming.

Comment: How would you represent a curve consisting of two straight lines, going from $(0,1)$ to $(0.3,0.3)$ and then to $(1,0)$?

Comment: @Hashimoto the recursive formula can be found in the Wikipedia link referenced above or [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html) (see (11) and (20)). However, the asymptotic formula is $p(n)\sim\frac{1}{4n\sqrt{3}}e^{\pi\sqrt{2n/3}}$, which suggests that OP's question 2 is pretty much hopeless (generating all partitions and optimization by brute force)

Comment: @Peter Košinár I have only considered the lines which pass through each division of the grid, as illustrated in OP's picture.

Comment: Would you mind addressing the issue of comparison between the total number of all increasing functions to the only convex ones over the same grid approach?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: I programmed and obtained the grid. Using this approach it is impossible to get all convex functions. I mean yes, it is possible over the grid and as an answer to the question. However, when $N\rightarrow\infty$ we do not get all the convex functions. I bet we are not even near. Consider the convex function which linearly decreases from $(0,1)$ to $(0.4,0.2)$ and again linearly decreases from $(0.4,0.2)$ to $(1,0)$. It is impossible to get this function with this approach. No mater how fine the grid is, there are infinitely many other functions which are not achieved..

Comment: I have the feeling that having such a discrete to continuous approach work, one needs probably a set of infinitely many different nicely chosen grids, instead of a single one.